# Medium-editor - link text selection is gone

Tags: jquery

I am using Medium-editor for content editor. I can able to create link by the help of link button, but while I moved the cursor to input box( link inputbox - placeholder txtbox) the text selection is gone. If it is possible to maintain selection?[Click to see the image reference](https://Anand-cmlmediasoft.tinytake.com/sf/NTI1MzQ0XzI3NTE5NTc)

Here I attached the image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `saveSelection()` method before you display the textbox to remember the selection.  Later, when you wish to restore it, just call `restoreSelection()`.

Internally, these helper methods are just calling `exportSelection()` and storing the selection data internally, and later calling `importSelection(selection)` and passing it the stored value.

There is some additional documentation about how these methods can be used, you can find it [here](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/API.md#selection-functions)

Example:

```
var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');

// ------------------

// Later, before you display your textbox
editor.saveSelection();
// Display the textbox

// ------------------

// Later, when you want to restore the selection to what it was before
editor.restoreSelection();
```